# SSH into Raspberry Pi seems to not execute a code

Tags: python, ssh, raspberry-pi, kivy, subprocess

I'm making a kivy app that executes a code on a Raspberry Pi by using SSH and subprocess, as indicated in this link:

https://laurabravopriegue.medium.com/run-scripts-on-your-raspberry-pi-from-a-mobile-app-using-kivy-efd00abaeaee

The code is as follow:

```
subprocess.call("ssh pi@{raspberry_ip} python {file_path}",shell=True)
```

Somehow it doesn't execute the code on the raspberry but it doesn't show any problems in the app, like crashing or other warnings. Help please. How do I know where's the problem?

Comment: you forgot prefix `f` to have `f-string` - `f"ssh pi@{raspberry_ip} python {file_path}"`

Comment: did you run code in console/terminal to see error messages? Usually SSH asks for password.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what string you try to send to `call()` - and try to use this string directly in console/terminal to see if it works.

Comment: @furas I'm currently using PyCharm to run the code and it doesn't show any error messages, however, nothing happens in the raspberry. I've already run the code of the Raspberry and it works fine but whenever I tried to call it via SSH nothing happens. It doesn't even ask for a password.

Comment: as I said if you use `"ssh pi@{raspberry_ip} python {file_path}"` then you send literally `"ssh pi@{raspberry_ip} python {file_path}"`, not `"ssh pi@192.169.0.1 python /user/home/script.py` - you have to use prefix `f` to have `f-string`.

Comment: other problem can be that [call()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) doesn't have to display text on screen, and it may not ask for password - you may need to use `PIPE` and send `password` using special functions. Maybe better use differen modules specially created for running code by `ssh`

Comment: [paramiko](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/client.html), [fabric](https://www.fabfile.org/). [pexpect / pxssh](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pxssh.html)

Comment: @furas I did what you suggested about the print in the terminal and it worked, my laptop ran the code of the raspberry. It also asked for the password. Now we tried doing it with subprocess but it didn't work.

Comment: I asked to `print( "ssh pi@{raspberry_ip} python {file_path}" )`

Comment: BTW: as I said `call` may not display messages but it may still wait for end of execution of `ssh`. You may need to use other methods from `subprocess` and use `PIPE` to catch text from `ssh` to display it.

Comment: @furas so, I made a passwordless ssh access in my laptop and ran the code in pycharm. It worked well. I'm waiting to see if it works now in my android app but I doubt it since I think I would need to create a passwordless ssh access for my phone as well, is there any way I could do that?

Comment: as I remeber `passwordless` need to generate keys `priv`, `pub` and put it in `.ssh` on both computers - but probably you can generate it on any other computer. So there shouldn't be problem to generate keys - but I don't know if you can add key to `.ssh` on android.

Comment: @furas I already created a key pair in my android phone through Termux and I can connect via ssh passwordless to the raspberry pi. The code runs in the raspberry but the kivy app still can't seem to connect to the raspberry.

Comment: Please build a command string, print it out and run it `cmd=f'ssh pi@{raspberry_ip} /full/path/to/python {file_path}'`